# How to detect if the computer is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: vba, x86, x86-64

How do you determine if the computer you are on is a 32-bit machine or a 64-bit machine?

I need this done in vba preferrably.

Comment: Why do you want it? This could be determined using `#IfWin64` `#Else` `#End If` to compile the relevant version and use a public variable Win = 64 or Win = 32.

Comment: @osknows: ... assuming the OP has Office 2010. The `VBA7` and `Win64` compilation constants were introduced in that version of office.

Comment: ... but I can now see that the OP accepted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255750/how-do-i-convert-this-program-to-work-on-a-64-bit-machine) of yours, so I guess it's safe to assume it's Office 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it from 
http://www.msoffice.us/Access/PDF/Extending%20VBA%20with%20APIs.pdf. Seems like it is working on mine.

```
Option Compare Database

Type SYSTEM_INFO
wProcessorArchitecture As Integer
wReserved As Integer
dwPageSize As Long
lpMinimumApplicationAddress As Long
lpMaximumApplicationAddress As Long
dwActiveProcessorMask As Long
dwNumberOrfProcessors As Long
dwProcessorType As Long
dwAllocationGranularity As Long
wProcessorLevel As Integer
wProcessorRevision As Integer
End Type

Declare Sub GetNativeSystemInfo Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemInfo As SYSTEM_INFO)
Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Function Is64BitProcessor() As Boolean
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 As Integer = 9
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 As Integer = 6
Dim si As SYSTEM_INFO
' call the API
GetNativeSystemInfo si
' check the struct
Is64BitProcessor = (si.wProcessorArchitecture = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 _
Or _
si.wProcessorArchitecture = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64)
End Function
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: NB: `Option Compare Database` only works in Access-VBA. Seems to work fine otherwise; correctly returns `False` on my computer. +1

Answer (score 6):

@Wouter Simon's answer is sort of on the right track, but really incomplete. It is missing a couple of `Declare` statements as well as some kind of explanation.

Therefore I believe it's worth presenting a more complete and working version here.

```
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hModule As Long, _
    ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long '()

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function IsWow64Process Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByRef Wow64Process As Long) As Long

Sub CheckWhetherIts64()

    Dim Its64 As Long
    Dim handle As Long

    handle = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), _
                   "IsWow64Process")

    If handle > 0 Then ' IsWow64Process function exists
        ' Now use the function to determine if
        ' we are running under Wow64

        IsWow64Process GetCurrentProcess(), Its64
    End If
    If Its64 = 1 Then
        MsgBox "it's a 64 bit process."
    End If
End Sub
```

Caveat:

> For compatibility with operating systems that do not support this function, call GetProcAddress to detect whether IsWow64Process is implemented in Kernel32.dll. If GetProcAddress succeeds, it is safe to call this function. Otherwise, WOW64 is not present. Note that this technique is not a reliable way to detect whether the operating system is a 64-bit version of Windows because the Kernel32.dll in current versions of 32-bit Windows also contains this function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yep, that looks better. It has been too long! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To determine whether the running Office is 64-bit or 32-bit:
Use IsWow64Process (answer from Jean-François Corbett).

To determine whether Windows is 64-bit or 32-bit:

```
Public Function isWin64bit() As Boolean
  isWin64bit = 0 < Len(Environ("ProgramW6432"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straightforward way is:

```
#If Win64 Then
    MsgBox "Win 64"
#Else
    MsgBox "Win 32"
#End If
```

Sometimes it is also useful to check whether your Office is 32 or 64 and use this information to access the correct key in registry. So you can do:

```
#If Win64 Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        MsgBox "Win 64 and Office 64" ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourApp
    #Else
        MsgBox "Win 64 and Office 32" ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\YourApp
    #End If
#Else
    MsgBox "Win 32 and Office 32" ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourApp
#End If
```

HTH

Comment: the condition "Win 32" is not necessarily true, as it's common to find 32-bit Excel on a 64-bit Windows.

Comment: That second section is clearly incorrect. The #Win64 compiler constant indicates you're running 64-bit office, if that's true #VBA7 is always true too. The #VBA7 constant indicates you're running Office 2010 or higher and has nothing to do at all with detecting 32- vs 64-bit. Running this code returns _"Win 32 and Office 32"_ on Win 64 and Office 32. Falo's answer can be used to differentiate if the computer is 64-bit when run in Office 32.

Comment: i do not know what your code is testing. It is replying my 64 bit machine is 32.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional compilation could be very useful, `WinXX` detects environment but not hardware properties, example below :

```
   Dim mVers   As String

Sub Init()

    #If Win64 Then
        mVers = "Win64" ' Win64=true, Win32=true, Win16= false
        Call VerCheck
    #ElseIf win32 Then
        mVers = "Win32"  ' Win32=true, Win16=false
        Call VerCheck
    #ElseIf win16 Then
        mVers = "Win16"  ' Win16=true
        Call VerCheck
    #End If

End Sub

Sub VerCheck()
    MsgBox "Version: " & mVers, vbInformation, "Version"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think VBA may be linked to the office version that is running and it really matters what type of process is running. This code snippet may help (VB6 code)

```
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hModule As Long, _
    ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetModuleHandleA" _

handle = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), _
               "IsWow64Process")

If handle > 0 Then ' IsWow64Process function exists
    ' Now use the function to determine if 
    ' we are running under Wow64
    IsWow64Process GetCurrentProcess(), bolFunc
End If
```

Comment: GetModuleHandle is undefined =/

Comment: Neither is GetCurrentProcess()

Comment: Did you use the updated example with the declares? The function is in the kernel32 lib (OS) and may not be available in VBA code. Instead you would have to make a vbscript file and use normal VB6 code.

Comment: I'm currently using this in a macro and I can't expand past that

Comment: Then it is probably not possible to detect the platform. You need to be able to load the IsWow64Process function from the kernel dll. It probably doesn't work in VBA